# C# - Return generic type as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

I'm trying to resolve a generic type `T` with a dictionary of types to instances.
When `T` is `IEnumerable<>`, I get a LINQ `Select` query with all instances from that dictionary. However, when I try to return that query, I cannot cast it back to `T`.  I get the following exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Func`2[DiContainer.IServicesContainer,System.Object],System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Tester.IService]'.
```

code:

```
  public T Resolve<T>()
        {
            Type typeToResolve = typeof(T);

            if (m_TypeToConcrete.ContainsKey(typeToResolve))
            {
                return (T)m_TypeToConcrete[typeToResolve].GetSingle();
            }

            if (DetermineIfExactlyIEnumerable(typeToResolve))
            {
                Type underlyingType = typeToResolve.GetGenericArguments().First();
                if (m_TypeToConcrete.ContainsKey(underlyingType))
                {
                    // Throws invalid cast exception
                    return (T)m_TypeToConcrete[underlyingType].GetEnumerable();
                }
            }
        }


 public class FactoryMethodsForType
    {
        private List<Func<IServicesContainer, object>> m_FactoryMethods;
        private IServicesContainer m_Container;

        public FactoryMethodsForType(IServicesContainer container)
        {
            m_Container = container;
            m_FactoryMethods = new List<Func<IServicesContainer, object>>();
        }

        public void AddFactoryMethod(Func<IServicesContainer, object> method)
        {
            m_FactoryMethods.Add(method);
        }

        public object GetSingle()
        {
            return m_FactoryMethods.Last().Invoke(m_Container);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetEnumerable()
        {
            // Lazy
            return m_FactoryMethods.Select(m => m.Invoke(m_Container));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `GetEnumerable` gets the enumerator of the dictionary. Did you mean to do `(T)m_TypeToConcrete[underlyingType]`

Comment: What's the type of `m_TypeToConcrete`? What's the message of the `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: You are trying to do too much in that method. The assumption here is that you are creating your own DI container. that second set of code looks like you are trying to create a ResolveAll method. You may need to review your design

Comment: `m_TypeToConcrete` is of type `Dictionary<Type, FactoryMethodsForType>`, and `GetEnumerable` is a method I wrote, it's below. I think what you mean is `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Keep it simple stupid (KISS) , I think if your expecting IEnumerable then go with IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Well get enumerable returns a IEnumerable<object> and my guess you wan't IEnumerable<MyType>?

Comment: Nope, MyType is already an IEnumerable

Comment: No what I meant was you are setting the T to IEnumerable<MyType> and trying to cast a  IEnumerable<object> to  IEnumerable<MyType>.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: No this is impossible without reflection or runtime compilation because of how Generics work. You can use reflection but this will cost you performance or compile some sort of a getter expression on the fly but this will cost you performance as well. My suggestion just make a ResolveAll like all other IoC containers.

Comment: It's different than ResolveAll because it's only one type. I don't mind using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Filip's solution, I used a solution using reflection, although with poor performance at the moment, to cast the `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<myType>` and cast it to `T`:

```
  Type underlyingType = typeToResolve.GetGenericArguments().First();
                if (m_TypeToConcrete.ContainsKey(underlyingType))
                {
                    MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.Cast));
                    IEnumerable<object> instances = m_TypeToConcrete[underlyingType].GetEnumerable();

                    return (T)castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(underlyingType).Invoke(instances, new object[] { instances });
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this trick for a similar problem.

```
public static class GenericCast
    {
        //This is the only way to create a real thread safe dictionary might not be required in you case you can make convertors during init of just not care for multi thread. The normal dictionary will work fine it might only call the compile a few times.
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>> creators = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>>();

        public static T CastAs<T>(this IEnumerable<object> data)
        {
            var dataType = typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments.First();

            var creator = creators.GetOrAdd(dataType, new Lazy<Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>(() => {
                var source = Expression.Parameter(
                    typeof(IEnumerable<object>));

                var call = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Enumerable), "Cast", new Type[] { dataType }, source);

                var cast = Expression.Convert(call, typeof(object));

                var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>(cast, source);

                return exp.Compile();
            }));

            return (T)creator.Value(data);
        }
    }
```

This method will have a cost in the first call but every other time you will have little perf impact. You can use it in you code like this

```
m_TypeToConcrete[underlyingType].GetEnumerable().CastAs<T>();
```